# Can't multi-GPU / multi-monitor with proprietary AMD drivers in Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: drivers, multiple-monitors, gpu, amd-graphics, gpu-driver

I've been troubleshooting for a while and haven't found much relevant info, hopefully someone can help me.

I just installed [ubuntu gnome 15.10](https://ubuntugnome.org/ubuntu-gnome-15-10-is-released/) on my computer and I got it working with the AMD proprietary drivers for three out of five monitors.

I have two monitors plugged into one GPU, two plugged into the second, and one plugged into the motherboard. I can't plug the last one into one of the graphics cards because they only support two digital inputs at a time.

The graphics cards are both MSI R9280X.

I am only getting a display on two monitors that are plugged into one of the GPUs.

In catalyst control center, it detects the other two in the other GPU, but not the one in the motherboard, although I know that the OS is capable of using that monitor because that screen flashes the ubuntu loading logo on boot sometimes.

Also, I can move my mouse to the other two monitors (which are also cloned for some reason) but my curser changes to a black "X".

By the way, I have gotten it to work with all five monitors before with a different installation, but I was using the non proprietary drivers. I can't use those drivers though because when I did, I got a whole slew of other bugs.

Any ideas on how to get the other three monitors to work with the second gpu and the motherboard? Any guidance is appreciated.

Here is the output of some relevant shell commands:

```
$ fglrxinfo
display: :1  screen: 0
OpenGL vendor string: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc.
OpenGL renderer string: AMD Radeon R9 200 Series              
OpenGL version string: 4.5.13399 Compatibility Profile Context 15.201.1151



display: :1  screen: 1
OpenGL vendor string: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc.
OpenGL renderer string: AMD Radeon R9 200 Series              
OpenGL version string: 4.5.13399 Compatibility Profile Context 15.201.1151

$ ls /var/lib/kms/fglrx-updates-core/
15.201
kernel-4.2.0-27-generic-x86_64

$ cat /etc/X11/xorg.conf
Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "aticonfig Layout"
    Screen      0  "amdcccle-Screen[2]-0" 1920 1050
    Screen         "amdcccle-Screen[2]-1" 908 0
    Screen         "aticonfig-Screen[0]-0" 3285 0
    Screen         "amdcccle-Screen[1]-1" 0 1050
EndSection

Section "Module"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier   "aticonfig-Monitor[0]-0"
    Option      "VendorName" "ATI Proprietary Driver"
    Option      "ModelName" "Generic Autodetecting Monitor"
    Option      "DPMS" "true"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier   "0-DFP5"
    Option      "VendorName" "ATI Proprietary Driver"
    Option      "ModelName" "Generic Autodetecting Monitor"
    Option      "DPMS" "true"
    Option      "PreferredMode" "1920x1080"
    Option      "TargetRefresh" "60"
    Option      "Position" "0 0"
    Option      "Rotate" "normal"
    Option      "Disable" "false"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier   "0-DFP9"
    Option      "VendorName" "ATI Proprietary Driver"
    Option      "ModelName" "Generic Autodetecting Monitor"
    Option      "DPMS" "true"
    Option      "PreferredMode" "1680x1050"
    Option      "TargetRefresh" "60"
    Option      "Position" "0 0"
    Option      "Rotate" "normal"
    Option      "Disable" "false"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier   "1-Default monitor"
    Option      "VendorName" "ATI Proprietary Driver"
    Option      "ModelName" "Generic Autodetecting Monitor"
    Option      "DPMS" "true"
    Option      "PreferredMode" "640x480"
    Option      "TargetRefresh" "60"
    Option      "Position" "0 0"
    Option      "Rotate" "normal"
    Option      "Disable" "false"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier   "1-DFP10"
    Option      "VendorName" "ATI Proprietary Driver"
    Option      "ModelName" "Generic Autodetecting Monitor"
    Option      "DPMS" "true"
    Option      "PreferredMode" "1920x1080"
    Option      "TargetRefresh" "60"
    Option      "Position" "0 0"
    Option      "Rotate" "normal"
    Option      "Disable" "false"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier   "1-DFP9"
    Option      "VendorName" "ATI Proprietary Driver"
    Option      "ModelName" "Generic Autodetecting Monitor"
    Option      "DPMS" "true"
    Option      "PreferredMode" "1680x1050"
    Option      "TargetRefresh" "60"
    Option      "Position" "0 0"
    Option      "Rotate" "normal"
    Option      "Disable" "false"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier  "aticonfig-Device[0]-0"
    Driver      "fglrx"
    Option      "Monitor-DFP9" "0-DFP9"
    BusID       "PCI:1:0:0"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier  "amdcccle-Device[2]-0"
    Driver      "fglrx"
    Option      "Monitor-DFP10" "1-DFP10"
    BusID       "PCI:2:0:0"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier  "amdcccle-Device[2]-1"
    Driver      "fglrx"
    Option      "Monitor-DFP9" "1-DFP9"
    BusID       "PCI:2:0:0"
    Screen      1
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier  "amdcccle-Device[1]-1"
    Driver      "fglrx"
    Option      "Monitor-DFP5" "0-DFP5"
    BusID       "PCI:1:0:0"
    Screen      1
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "aticonfig-Screen[0]-0"
    Device     "aticonfig-Device[0]-0"
    DefaultDepth     24
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     24
    EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "amdcccle-Screen[2]-0"
    Device     "amdcccle-Device[2]-0"
    DefaultDepth     24
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     24
    EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "amdcccle-Screen[2]-1"
    Device     "amdcccle-Device[2]-1"
    DefaultDepth     24
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     24
    EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "amdcccle-Screen[1]-1"
    Device     "amdcccle-Device[1]-1"
    DefaultDepth     24
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     24
    EndSubSection
EndSection


$ lshw.txt
eo2ubuntu
    description: Computer
    width: 64 bits
    capabilities: smbios-2.7 vsyscall32
  *-core
       description: Motherboard
       physical id: 0
     *-memory
      description: System memory
      physical id: 0
      size: 31GiB
     *-cpu
      product: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4790K CPU @ 4.00GHz
      vendor: Intel Corp.
      physical id: 1
      bus info: cpu@0
      size: 4378MHz
      capacity: 4400MHz
      width: 64 bits
      capabilities: fpu fpu_exception wp vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp x86-64 constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf eagerfpu pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 fma cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm abm ida arat pln pts dtherm tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 hle avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid rtm xsaveopt cpufreq
     *-pci
      description: Host bridge
      product: 4th Gen Core Processor DRAM Controller
      vendor: Intel Corporation
      physical id: 100
      bus info: pci@0000:00:00.0
      version: 06
      width: 32 bits
      clock: 33MHz
      configuration: driver=hsw_uncore
      resources: irq:0
    *-pci:0
         description: PCI bridge
         product: Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor PCI Express x16 Controller
         vendor: Intel Corporation
         physical id: 1
         bus info: pci@0000:00:01.0
         version: 06
         width: 32 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: pci pm msi pciexpress normal_decode bus_master cap_list
         configuration: driver=pcieport
         resources: irq:26 ioport:e000(size=4096) memory:dee00000-deefffff ioport:b0000000(size=268435456)
       *-display
            description: VGA compatible controller
            product: Tahiti XT [Radeon HD 7970/8970 OEM / R9 280X]
            vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
            physical id: 0
            bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
            version: 00
            width: 64 bits
            clock: 33MHz
            capabilities: pm pciexpress msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
            configuration: driver=fglrx_pci latency=0
            resources: irq:42 memory:b0000000-bfffffff memory:dee00000-dee3ffff ioport:e000(size=256) memory:dee40000-dee5ffff
       *-multimedia
            description: Audio device
            product: Tahiti XT HDMI Audio [Radeon HD 7970 Series]
            vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
            physical id: 0.1
            bus info: pci@0000:01:00.1
            version: 00
            width: 64 bits
            clock: 33MHz
            capabilities: pm pciexpress msi bus_master cap_list
            configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=0
            resources: irq:39 memory:dee60000-dee63fff
    *-pci:1
         description: PCI bridge
         product: Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor PCI Express x8 Controller
         vendor: Intel Corporation
         physical id: 1.1
         bus info: pci@0000:00:01.1
         version: 06
         width: 32 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: pci pm msi pciexpress normal_decode bus_master cap_list
         configuration: driver=pcieport
         resources: irq:27 ioport:d000(size=4096) memory:ded00000-dedfffff ioport:a0000000(size=268435456)
       *-display
            description: VGA compatible controller
            product: Tahiti XT [Radeon HD 7970/8970 OEM / R9 280X]
            vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
            physical id: 0
            bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
            version: 00
            width: 64 bits
            clock: 33MHz
            capabilities: pm pciexpress msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
            configuration: driver=fglrx_pci latency=0
            resources: irq:43 memory:a0000000-afffffff memory:ded00000-ded3ffff ioport:d000(size=256) memory:ded40000-ded5ffff
       *-multimedia
            description: Audio device
            product: Tahiti XT HDMI Audio [Radeon HD 7970 Series]
            vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
            physical id: 0.1
            bus info: pci@0000:02:00.1
            version: 00
            width: 64 bits
            clock: 33MHz
            capabilities: pm pciexpress msi bus_master cap_list
            configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=0
            resources: irq:40 memory:ded60000-ded63fff
    *-display
         description: Display controller
         product: Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller
         vendor: Intel Corporation
         physical id: 2
         bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
         version: 06
         width: 64 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: msi pm bus_master cap_list
         configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
         resources: irq:36 memory:de400000-de7fffff memory:50000000-5fffffff ioport:f000(size=64)
    *-multimedia:0
         description: Audio device
         product: Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor HD Audio Controller
         vendor: Intel Corporation
         physical id: 3
         bus info: pci@0000:00:03.0
         version: 06
         width: 64 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
         configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=0
         resources: irq:41 memory:def34000-def37fff
    *-usb:0
         description: USB controller
         product: 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI
         vendor: Intel Corporation
         physical id: 14
         bus info: pci@0000:00:14.0
         version: 05
         width: 64 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: pm msi xhci bus_master cap_list
         configuration: driver=xhci_hcd latency=0
         resources: irq:32 memory:def20000-def2ffff
       *-usbhost:0
            product: xHCI Host Controller
            vendor: Linux 4.2.0-27-generic xhci-hcd
            physical id: 0
            bus info: usb@2
            logical name: usb2
            version: 4.02
            capabilities: usb-3.00
            configuration: driver=hub slots=6 speed=5000Mbit/s
          *-usb:0
               description: USB hub
               vendor: Hitachi, Ltd
               physical id: 5
               bus info: usb@2:5
               version: 1.00
               capabilities: usb-3.00
               configuration: driver=hub slots=4 speed=5000Mbit/s
          *-usb:1
               description: USB hub
               vendor: Hitachi, Ltd
               physical id: 6
               bus info: usb@2:6
               version: 1.00
               capabilities: usb-3.00
               configuration: driver=hub slots=4 speed=5000Mbit/s
       *-usbhost:1
            product: xHCI Host Controller
            vendor: Linux 4.2.0-27-generic xhci-hcd
            physical id: 1
            bus info: usb@1
            logical name: usb1
            version: 4.02
            capabilities: usb-2.00
            configuration: driver=hub slots=14 speed=480Mbit/s
          *-usb:0
               description: Generic USB device
               product: BCM20702A0
               vendor: Broadcom Corp
               physical id: 4
               bus info: usb@1:4
               version: 1.12
               serial: 240A646F066C
               capabilities: usb-2.00
               configuration: driver=btusb speed=12Mbit/s
          *-usb:1
               description: USB hub
               vendor: Hitachi, Ltd
               physical id: 9
               bus info: usb@1:9
               version: 1.00
               capabilities: usb-2.10
               configuration: driver=hub slots=4 speed=480Mbit/s
             *-usb
                  description: USB hub
                  product: Hub in Apple Extended USB Keyboard
                  vendor: Mitsumi Electric
                  physical id: 3
                  bus info: usb@1:9.3
                  version: 4.00
                  capabilities: usb-1.10
                  configuration: driver=hub maxpower=50mA slots=3 speed=12Mbit/s
                *-usb
                     description: Keyboard
                     product: Apple Extended USB Keyboard
                     vendor: Mitsumi Electric
                     physical id: 3
                     bus info: usb@1:9.3.3
                     version: 4.00
                     capabilities: usb-1.10
                     configuration: driver=usbhid maxpower=50mA speed=12Mbit/s
          *-usb:2
               description: USB hub
               vendor: Hitachi, Ltd
               physical id: a
               bus info: usb@1:a
               version: 1.00
               capabilities: usb-2.10
               configuration: driver=hub slots=4 speed=480Mbit/s
             *-usb
                  description: Keyboard
                  product: USB Receiver
                  vendor: Logitech
                  physical id: 2
                  bus info: usb@1:a.2
                  version: 12.03
                  capabilities: usb-2.00
                  configuration: driver=usbhid maxpower=98mA speed=12Mbit/s
    *-communication
         description: Communication controller
         product: 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1
         vendor: Intel Corporation
         physical id: 16
         bus info: pci@0000:00:16.0
         version: 04
         width: 64 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list
         configuration: driver=mei_me latency=0
         resources: irq:37 memory:def3f000-def3f00f
    *-network
         description: Ethernet interface
         product: Ethernet Connection I217-V
         vendor: Intel Corporation
         physical id: 19
         bus info: pci@0000:00:19.0
         logical name: eno1
         version: 05
         serial: 74:d4:35:18:ea:3b
         size: 1Gbit/s
         capacity: 1Gbit/s
         width: 32 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
         configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=3.2.5-k duplex=full firmware=0.13-4 ip=10.1.0.73 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
         resources: irq:35 memory:def00000-def1ffff memory:def3d000-def3dfff ioport:f080(size=32)
    *-usb:1
         description: USB controller
         product: 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI #2
         vendor: Intel Corporation
         physical id: 1a
         bus info: pci@0000:00:1a.0
         version: 05
         width: 32 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: pm debug ehci bus_master cap_list
         configuration: driver=ehci-pci latency=0
         resources: irq:16 memory:def3c000-def3c3ff
       *-usbhost
            product: EHCI Host Controller
            vendor: Linux 4.2.0-27-generic ehci_hcd
            physical id: 1
            bus info: usb@3
            logical name: usb3
            version: 4.02
            capabilities: usb-2.00
            configuration: driver=hub slots=2 speed=480Mbit/s
          *-usb
               description: USB hub
               vendor: Intel Corp.
               physical id: 1
               bus info: usb@3:1
               version: 0.05
               capabilities: usb-2.00
               configuration: driver=hub slots=6 speed=480Mbit/s
    *-multimedia:1
         description: Audio device
         product: 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset High Definition Audio Controller
         vendor: Intel Corporation
         physical id: 1b
         bus info: pci@0000:00:1b.0
         version: 05
         width: 64 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
         configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=0
         resources: irq:38 memory:def30000-def33fff
    *-pci:2
         description: PCI bridge
         product: 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #1
         vendor: Intel Corporation
         physical id: 1c
         bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.0
         version: d5
         width: 32 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
         configuration: driver=pcieport
         resources: irq:16 ioport:2000(size=4096) memory:c0000000-de0fffff ioport:60000000(size=973078528)
    *-pci:3
         description: PCI bridge
         product: 82801 PCI Bridge
         vendor: Intel Corporation
         physical id: 1c.4
         bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.4
         version: d5
         width: 32 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm subtractive_decode bus_master cap_list
       *-pci
            description: PCI bridge
            product: 82801 PCI Bridge
            vendor: Intel Corporation
            physical id: 0
            bus info: pci@0000:6e:00.0
            version: 41
            width: 32 bits
            clock: 33MHz
            capabilities: pci pm subtractive_decode bus_master cap_list
    *-pci:4
         description: PCI bridge
         product: 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #6
         vendor: Intel Corporation
         physical id: 1c.5
         bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.5
         version: d5
         width: 32 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
         configuration: driver=pcieport
         resources: irq:17 ioport:c000(size=4096) memory:dec00000-decfffff
       *-storage
            description: SATA controller
            product: 88SE9172 SATA 6Gb/s Controller
            vendor: Marvell Technology Group Ltd.
            physical id: 0
            bus info: pci@0000:70:00.0
            version: 11
            width: 32 bits
            clock: 33MHz
            capabilities: storage pm msi pciexpress ahci_1.0 bus_master cap_list rom
            configuration: driver=ahci latency=0
            resources: irq:34 ioport:c040(size=8) ioport:c030(size=4) ioport:c020(size=8) ioport:c010(size=4) ioport:c000(size=16) memory:dec10000-dec101ff memory:dec00000-dec0ffff
    *-pci:5
         description: PCI bridge
         product: 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #7
         vendor: Intel Corporation
         physical id: 1c.6
         bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.6
         version: d5
         width: 32 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
         configuration: driver=pcieport
         resources: irq:18 ioport:3000(size=4096) memory:de800000-debfffff ioport:4fa00000(size=2097152)
       *-pci
            description: PCI bridge
            product: PEX 8605 PCI Express 4-port Gen2 Switch
            vendor: PLX Technology, Inc.
            physical id: 0
            bus info: pci@0000:71:00.0
            version: aa
            width: 32 bits
            clock: 33MHz
            capabilities: pci pm msi pciexpress normal_decode bus_master cap_list
            configuration: driver=pcieport
            resources: irq:28 memory:deb00000-deb03fff ioport:3000(size=4096) memory:de800000-deafffff ioport:4fa00000(size=2097152)
          *-pci:0
               description: PCI bridge
               product: PEX 8605 PCI Express 4-port Gen2 Switch
               vendor: PLX Technology, Inc.
               physical id: 1
               bus info: pci@0000:72:01.0
               version: aa
               width: 32 bits
               clock: 33MHz
               capabilities: pci pm msi pciexpress normal_decode bus_master cap_list
               configuration: driver=pcieport
               resources: irq:29 ioport:3000(size=4096) ioport:4fa00000(size=2097152)
          *-pci:1
               description: PCI bridge
               product: PEX 8605 PCI Express 4-port Gen2 Switch
               vendor: PLX Technology, Inc.
               physical id: 2
               bus info: pci@0000:72:02.0
               version: aa
               width: 32 bits
               clock: 33MHz
               capabilities: pci pm msi pciexpress normal_decode bus_master cap_list
               configuration: driver=pcieport
               resources: irq:30
          *-pci:2
               description: PCI bridge
               product: PEX 8605 PCI Express 4-port Gen2 Switch
               vendor: PLX Technology, Inc.
               physical id: 3
               bus info: pci@0000:72:03.0
               version: aa
               width: 32 bits
               clock: 33MHz
               capabilities: pci pm msi pciexpress normal_decode bus_master cap_list
               configuration: driver=pcieport
               resources: irq:31 memory:de800000-deafffff
             *-network
                  description: Wireless interface
                  product: BCM4352 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
                  vendor: Broadcom Corporation
                  physical id: 0
                  bus info: pci@0000:75:00.0
                  logical name: wlp117s0
                  version: 03
                  serial: 24:0a:64:95:85:25
                  width: 64 bits
                  clock: 33MHz
                  capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
                  configuration: broadcast=yes driver=wl0 driverversion=6.30.223.248 (r487574) latency=0 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abg
                  resources: irq:17 memory:dea00000-dea07fff memory:de800000-de9fffff
    *-usb:2
         description: USB controller
         product: 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI #1
         vendor: Intel Corporation
         physical id: 1d
         bus info: pci@0000:00:1d.0
         version: 05
         width: 32 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: pm debug ehci bus_master cap_list
         configuration: driver=ehci-pci latency=0
         resources: irq:23 memory:def3b000-def3b3ff
       *-usbhost
            product: EHCI Host Controller
            vendor: Linux 4.2.0-27-generic ehci_hcd
            physical id: 1
            bus info: usb@4
            logical name: usb4
            version: 4.02
            capabilities: usb-2.00
            configuration: driver=hub slots=2 speed=480Mbit/s
          *-usb
               description: USB hub
               vendor: Intel Corp.
               physical id: 1
               bus info: usb@4:1
               version: 0.05
               capabilities: usb-2.00
               configuration: driver=hub slots=8 speed=480Mbit/s
    *-isa
         description: ISA bridge
         product: Z87 Express LPC Controller
         vendor: Intel Corporation
         physical id: 1f
         bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.0
         version: 05
         width: 32 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: isa bus_master cap_list
         configuration: driver=lpc_ich latency=0
         resources: irq:0
    *-storage
         description: SATA controller
         product: 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller 1 [AHCI mode]
         vendor: Intel Corporation
         physical id: 1f.2
         bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.2
         version: 05
         width: 32 bits
         clock: 66MHz
         capabilities: storage msi pm ahci_1.0 bus_master cap_list
         configuration: driver=ahci latency=0
         resources: irq:33 ioport:f0d0(size=8) ioport:f0c0(size=4) ioport:f0b0(size=8) ioport:f0a0(size=4) ioport:f060(size=32) memory:def3a000-def3a7ff
    *-serial UNCLAIMED
         description: SMBus
         product: 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller
         vendor: Intel Corporation
         physical id: 1f.3
         bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.3
         version: 05
         width: 64 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         configuration: latency=0
         resources: memory:def39000-def390ff ioport:f040(size=32)
     *-scsi:0
      physical id: 2
      logical name: scsi1
      capabilities: emulated
    *-disk
         description: ATA Disk
         product: ST9160823ASG
         vendor: Seagate
         physical id: 0.0.0
         bus info: scsi@1:0.0.0
         logical name: /dev/sda
         version: B
         serial: 5NK0LXZ4
         size: 149GiB (160GB)
         capabilities: gpt-1.00 partitioned partitioned:gpt
         configuration: ansiversion=5 guid=3456691e-9e63-4cf2-a9a9-09796c3d7f98 logicalsectorsize=512 sectorsize=512
       *-volume:0 UNCLAIMED
            description: Windows FAT volume
            vendor: mkfs.fat
            physical id: 1
            bus info: scsi@1:0.0.0,1
            version: FAT32
            serial: af7a-644c
            size: 510MiB
            capacity: 511MiB
            capabilities: boot fat initialized
            configuration: FATs=2 filesystem=fat name=EFI System Partition
       *-volume:1
            description: EXT4 volume
            vendor: Linux
            physical id: 2
            bus info: scsi@1:0.0.0,2
            logical name: /dev/sda2
            logical name: /
            version: 1.0
            serial: 894f146e-a942-450a-b138-2459b31ee740
            size: 116GiB
            capabilities: journaled extended_attributes large_files huge_files dir_nlink recover extents ext4 ext2 initialized
            configuration: created=2016-02-13 18:24:56 filesystem=ext4 lastmountpoint=/ modified=2016-02-13 21:05:08 mount.fstype=ext4 mount.options=rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered mounted=2016-02-13 21:05:14 state=mounted
       *-volume:2
            description: Linux swap volume
            vendor: Linux
            physical id: 3
            bus info: scsi@1:0.0.0,3
            logical name: /dev/sda3
            version: 1
            serial: bab9a160-49bc-4510-b846-d44a2508f270
            size: 31GiB
            capacity: 31GiB
            capabilities: nofs swap initialized
            configuration: filesystem=swap pagesize=4095
     *-scsi:1
      physical id: 3
      logical name: scsi4
      capabilities: emulated
    *-disk
         description: ATA Disk
         product: Crucial_CT512MX1
         physical id: 0.0.0
         bus info: scsi@4:0.0.0
         logical name: /dev/sdb
         version: MU01
         serial: 14400D6D492A
         size: 476GiB (512GB)
         capabilities: partitioned partitioned:dos
         configuration: ansiversion=5 logicalsectorsize=512 sectorsize=4096 signature=49855669
       *-volume:0
            description: Windows NTFS volume
            physical id: 1
            bus info: scsi@4:0.0.0,1
            logical name: /dev/sdb1
            version: 3.1
            serial: c60b351d-f3fd-b745-a7d2-2d9fcc627d73
            size: 348MiB
            capacity: 350MiB
            capabilities: primary bootable ntfs initialized
            configuration: clustersize=4096 created=2015-02-06 16:28:38 filesystem=ntfs label=System Reserved modified_by_chkdsk=true mounted_on_nt4=true resize_log_file=true state=dirty upgrade_on_mount=true
       *-volume:1
            description: Windows NTFS volume
            physical id: 2
            bus info: scsi@4:0.0.0,2
            logical name: /dev/sdb2
            version: 3.1
            serial: fe0cc28e-d4a3-3d44-a0ff-34cfdadcd650
            size: 476GiB
            capacity: 476GiB
            capabilities: primary ntfs initialized
            configuration: clustersize=4096 created=2015-02-06 16:28:49 filesystem=ntfs modified_by_chkdsk=true mounted_on_nt4=true resize_log_file=true state=dirty upgrade_on_mount=true
       *-volume:2
            description: Windows NTFS volume
            physical id: 3
            bus info: scsi@4:0.0.0,3
            logical name: /dev/sdb3
            version: 3.1
            serial: 6e0c-9c74
            size: 418MiB
            capacity: 450MiB
            capabilities: primary ntfs initialized
            configuration: clustersize=4096 created=2015-07-29 18:34:01 filesystem=ntfs modified_by_chkdsk=true mounted_on_nt4=true resize_log_file=true state=dirty upgrade_on_mount=true
```

Comment: Im no expert, but i think in general open-source drivers tend to work better with more software and proprietary drivers tend to have better performance.